# How to handle nested forms in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cocoon-gem

Hello all I am using cocoon gem to build nested forms.

```
has_many :filled_cartridges, inverse_of: :request, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :filled_cartridges, allow_destroy: true
```

This is my request model.

Inside `request.html.erb` I have:

```
<%= f.fields_for :filled_cartridges do |filled_cartridge| %>
   <fieldset class="nested-fields"> 
     <%= filled_cartridge.autocomplete_field :cartridge_name, autocomplete_cartridge_cartridge_name_requests_path, :update_elements => {} %>
     <%= filled_cartridge.hidden_field :_destroy %>
     <%= link_to_remove_association "удалить", f %>
   </fieldset>  
<% end %>
```

Strong Params:

```
def request_params
  params.require(:request).permit(:name, :address,:filled_cartridges_attributes => [:client_id,:cartridge_name,:cartridge_id,
                :request_id,:count,:fill_date,:_destroy,:id],)
end
```

So I have destroy and id params in order to be able destroy records.
I want to handle my request and filled cartridges model in one instance. I believe I can do that thanks to accepts_nested_attributes.

The problem is that it cant save filled_Cartridge:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: filled_cartridges.client_id
```

I guess the problem is inside the controller method:

```
@request = Request.new( request_params )
@client = Client.where("name = ?", @request.name).take

if params[:request][:filled_cartridges_attributes].present? and params[:stype_ids].present?
    if params[:stype_ids].include? '1'
        params[:request][:filled_cartridges_attributes].each do |_,value|
            if @client.present?
                value[:client_id] = @client.id
            else
                value[:client_id] = 0
            end
                value[:request_id] = 0  #временный id
                @cartridge = Cartridge.where('cartridge_name=?', "#{value[:cartridge_name]}").take
            if @cartridge.nil?
                @cartridge = Cartridge.create!(:cartridge_name => "#{value[:cartridge_name]}")
        end
            value[:cartridge_id] = @cartridge.id
            value[:cartridge_name] = @cartridge.cartridge_name
        end
    end
end
```

NOTE: Can i set params like value[:parm] = something

Comment: Have you tried this ?
`<%= filled_cartridge.autocomplete_field :cartridge_name, autocomplete_cartridge_cartridge_name_requests_path, :update_elements => {} %>`
`<%= filled_cartridge.hidden_field :_destroy %>`

Comment: @Amit Sharma, by the way it is just typo, the fieldset was initially in partial. Ignore it

Comment: Why is this question tagged with both [tag:ruby-on-rails-4] and [tag:ruby-on-rails-3.2]?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with your nested forms, it has to do with a not null constraint in your SQLite schema.  Either pass in your client_id to validate the constraint or remove the constraint from the db

Comment: yep, but the problem that i can not assign some value to client_id, and removing the constraint will just let the record be saved with empty values. but i need values.